# How can I get multiple lists of individual values, from a single list of options for each value?

Tags: python

I have a list of `scores`, e.g. `[60, 60, 60, 30, 60, 57, 57, 57]`, and a lookup dict `all_scores_to_numerical_scores`. The `scores` represent point values for an individual dart in a game of darts, and the lookup indicates ways to get that score.

When I use

```
[all_scores_to_numerical_scores[score] for score in scores]
```

I get a result like

```
[['T20'], ['T20'], ['T20'], ['D15', 'T10'], ['T20'], ['T19'], ['T19'], ['T19']]
```

That is, each nested list shows values corresponding to one of the original `scores`. I want to get a result like this instead:

```
[['T20'], ['T20'], ['T20'], ['D15'], ['T20'], ['T19'], ['T19'], ['T19']]
[['T20'], ['T20'], ['T20'], ['T10'], ['T20'], ['T19'], ['T19'], ['T19']]
```

That is, multiple lists, each of which shows a single way to obtain all of the scores.

How can I do this?

Comment: It seems to me that all you need is the `itertools.product` of the resulting list, to get the two lists you want.  This will also handle multiple choices in other list positions.

Comment: The operation you are looking for is called the *cartesian product* of the sublists. I have linked a useful duplicate, and would also encourage you to read the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) on the topic.

Comment: I removed the `defaultdict` tag because the tags are supposed to be for things involved in the part you need help with, not the part that already works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` to get all possible outcomes. As your program will calculate how you can get a specific score at a time into lists, then you can use that output to `product` method as following:

```
from itertools import product

game_possibilities = [['T20'], ['T20'], ['T20'], ['D15','T10'], ['T20'], ['T19'], ['T19'], ['T19']]
game_branches = product(*game_possibilites)

# output
[('T20', 'T20', 'T20', 'D15', 'T20', 'T19', 'T19', 'T19'), ('T20', 'T20', 'T20', 'T10', 'T20', 'T19', 'T19', 'T19')]
```

If you want every value as list (as in question) you can convert the final data to list as:

```
final_output = [list([v] for v in x) for x in game_branches]
```